# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined when property is defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Simple code to switch tabs. This is how I realize it with hooks and everything works.

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const switchingTabs = (e, value) => {
    console.log(value);

    setState(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <AppBar className="bar" position="static">
          <Tabs value={state} onChange={switchingTabs}>
            <Tab label="tab 1"></Tab>
            <Tab label="tab 2"></Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        <TabBackbone value={state} index={0}></TabBackbone>
        <TabBackbone value={state} index={1}></TabBackbone>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when I tried to use class components its send me error "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" , but console log says that value has a property.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tab: 0 };
  }

  switchingTabs(event, value) {
    console.log(value);

    this.setState({
      tab: value,
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Container>
          <AppBar className="bar" position="static">
            <Tabs value={this.state.tab} onChange={this.switchingTabs}>
              <Tab label="tab 1"></Tab>
              <Tab label="tab 2"></Tab>
            </Tabs>
          </AppBar>
          <TabBackbone value={this.state.tab} index={0}></TabBackbone>
          <TabBackbone value={this.state.tab} index={1}></TabBackbone>
          <Content></Content>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to bind the function in the constructor

`this.switchingTabs = this.switchingTabs.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind `switchingTabs`;

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tab: 0 };
    this.switchingTabs= this.switchingTabs.bind(this);
}
```

Or you can define the function as expression;

```
  switchingTabs = (event, value) => {
    ...
  }
```